# May one say Yehi Ratzon prayers at any time?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, time

Take the Yehi Ratzon recited before Hamapil (at least, in my nusach ashkenaz). May one recite it in the mornings, with the rest of his tefillos during Shemoneh Esrei, for instance? Or must it be said at night, in its place in the Siddur?

<sub>If your answer is that specifically by this example it can't be moved, although that could contribute to a good answer, it wouldn't be a full answer, as I'm asking about Yehi Ratzon prayers *in general*, not that one in particular.</sub>

Comment: The *Yehi Ratzon* that's before Hamapil seems general enough in context to b esaid any time of the day. My shul has a minhag to recite it before the first Selichot. However, in terms of the one before Hamapil, it seems most appropriate to say it at the end of the day, as you're forgiving people who angered you throughout the day and, hopefully, just before you sleep, no one will anger you. (Including your spouse or kids!) If you said it beforehand, there's still a chance that someone would irk you. Please specify which other *Yehi Ratzon* you mean. There's loads of them around!!!

Comment: @DanF Exactly. My question is regarding any such Tefillah that, although placed in one place in davening, is written in such a way that it could be said at any other time. Was it designated for that time specifically, or can you say it at any time?

Comment: Well many *Yehi Ratzon* are specifically placed before a mitzvah. There's one before *sefirat ha'omer*, another before *Ushpizin* prior to eating your Succah meal, another before shaking the lulav, one before blowing shofar, etc. It wouldn't make sense to move those anywhere else. Can you give examples of others  that are unlike these that you thnnk could be moved?

Comment: @DanF Perhaps the one commonly said after Birchas HaShachar, about saving one from various troubles throughout the day. Again, it makes sense for it to be said at the beginning of the day, but it's still a normal Tefillah that could perhaps be said later in Shacharis, for instance.

Comment: what is the hava amina that all is fixed?

Comment: Saying them at some other time can't be worse than omitting them entirely. This shouldn't be the biggest problem. They arent formal parts of prayer; just nice prayers composed fairly recently. The 'yehi ratson' before hamapil is largely taken from Berakhot 17a as a prayer that Rava said after he prayed. That is; it was not originally associated with the time one goes to sleep.

Comment: @mevaqesh I think you have an answer! There are probably some other similar examples. Come to think of it, I think that the *yehi Ratzon* that we now use for Birkat Hachodesh was originally somewhere else. It was adapted to include a small phrase about blessing the upcoming month, otherwise, the rest is from somewhere else.

Comment: @DanF I left it in a comment since it is difficult to prove a negative. Furthermore, one wold have to go through every single yehi ratson everywhere, since the OP asked about all of them, and prove that none of them are obligation.

Comment: @mevaqesh This may end up being an unanswerable questions. I would agree that there is probably not a single obligatory "Yehi Ratzon" type prayer around. However, as I mentioned, if one is saying them (which seems to be OP's premise), there are those that can't be moved because of their context / content and others that probably can, such as the one that you mentioned as well as "Tefillat Rav" that I alluded to (adapted to become Birkat Hachodesh.) I think OP might wantto clarify further what he is seeking.

Comment: I believe one can compose and recite his own yehi ratzon at any time with any words and pray for whatever he wants. If that's true, there shouldn't be any problem with basing your yehi ratzon on one found elsewhere.